# Join 2 Table in postgresql but the other table only will extract its columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way in postgres when you `join` 2 Table but you only extract the columns of the first table using '*' symbol which means all of the columns of the first table.

Comment: Use the table alias/table name before the `*`.

Comment: can you show me some sample sir. thanks

Comment: thanks mr. @GordonLinoff . it works. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this one because I solved it by the help of Mr.@Gordon Linoff.

I use the `alias` of the table and use it in the `*` symbol.

sample code below:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table_a as a join table_b as b ON a.id=b.id;
```

This will only extract the data of `table_a`.